# Grabbing one or more shapes from a canvas

Tags: javascript, html, html5-canvas

I have a canvas with some shapes in it (ovals, triangles, squares) , my question is of I can get a reference to one of the objects and animate it when an event happens.

Thank you for your time. I hope it's not a stupid question.

Comment: Please include some code. It's hard to understand the scope atm.

Comment: There is no way to do so..You will have to redraw entire canvas considering new positions of the elements..

Comment: You can hit-test a shape (shape==path) with [isPointInPath](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22129893/draw-polygon-shape-on-canvas-and-allow-tooltip-on-it/22131147#22131147). You can't move a shape but you can [redraw it in a moved position to simulate animation](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/31736803/html5-canvas-draw-multiple-rectangles-that-move-in-the-canvas/31736969#31736969)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Canvas doesn't store the handle of all the objects you paint on it, so in essence you will have to paint the entire canvas again.

But there are libraries which can help you in doing that. Have you tried [fabric.js](http://fabricjs.com/) and its [examples on animation](http://fabricjs.com/fabric-intro-part-2/#animation) on shapes and images?

```
rect.animate('angle', 45, {
  onChange: canvas.renderAll.bind(canvas)
});
```

Comment: Thank you. This seems to be what I need.  Do you happen to know if there are any problems if i integrate this in an AngularJS based application?